Powershell: How to add a column to an existing CSV?
I've seen a lot of instances of people trying to do different things with CSVs in Powershell, I'm fairly new to CSVs and I haven't seen anyone trying to do quite what I am. Here's the short version: I've written a script that gathers a lot of information about subfolders of whatever directory the PS1 is sitting in, and outputs the folder names and file counts to a CSV file.
So column A has all the folder names, column B has the file counts in each folder, with the value of Get-Date as the column header; all I want to do is each time I run the script, have it append a new column of data, with the value of Get-Date as the column header and the file counts for that instance of the script.
Trouble is, no matter how I change up the Export-CSV command, either nothing happens or I get a strange result that's not what I'm looking for (for instance, with the code sample below, when I run it the first time it works perfectly, but when I run it the second time it creates a second series of rows below the first one with no additional data).
I know this has to be absurdly simple but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make it do this. Can folks around here help me out? (And please...I've read through more help articles than I can count, on everything from Add-Member to Join, and I can't find an answer, so if you reply please provide a code sample that I can work with)
Code:
$sourceDir = $PSScriptRoot
$parentFolder = (Split-Path $sourceDir -Parent)
$thisDrive = (Split-Path -Path $sourceDir -Qualifier) + "\"
$columnDate = (Get-Date)

If ($sourceDir -eq $thisDrive)
    {
    $thisFolderName = "ROOT";
    } else {
    $thisFolderName = (Split-Path -Path $sourceDir -Leaf)
    }

$newFileName = "_Folder-Stats_" + $thisFolderName + "_AND_SUBFOLDERS_Ongoing.csv"
$outputFile = $sourceDir + $newFileName
$scriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand;
$thisScript = ($sourceDir + $scriptName)

Write-Host "OPERATION: Determine Folder Size and Quantify Contents (SOURCEDIR-ROOT Only) & Export CSV" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkGreen;
Write-Host "SOURCEDIR: " -NoNewline;
Write-Host "'$sourceDir'" -ForegroundColor Yellow;
Write-Host "THISDRIVE: " -NoNewline;
Write-Host "'$thisDrive'" -ForegroundColor Yellow;
Write-Host "THISFOLDERNAME: " -NoNewline;
Write-Host "'$thisFolderName'" -ForegroundColor Yellow;
Write-Host "OUTPUTFILE: " -NoNewline;
Write-Host "'$outputFile'" -ForegroundColor Yellow;

Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Beginning operation " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
Write-Host "GET-CHILDITEM" -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host " on " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
Write-Host "SOURCEDIR" -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "..." -ForegroundColor White -NoNewLine

$rootFolders = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourceDir -Directory)

Write-Host "operation complete." -ForegroundColor Green

$numFolders = ($rootFolders | Measure-Object ).Count;
$displayFolders = ('{0:N0}' -f $numFolders)

Write-Host " "
Write-Host "Total Folders Found:        " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
Write-Host $displayFolders -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewLine
Write-Host " folders"
Write-Host " "

Write-Host "Beginning " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
Write-Host "FOREACH" -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host " operation, please wait..." -ForegroundColor White
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "============================================================" -ForegroundColor Green

$i = 0;
$folderSummary = foreach($thisFolder in $rootFolders.FullName) {
    $i += 1;
    $folderName = Split-Path $thisFolder -Leaf

    Write-Host "FOREACH: " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "Folder $i of $displayFolders" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host "FOREACH:GET-CHILDITEM" -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host " on folder " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host $thisFolder -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "." -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host "FOREACH:FOLDERNAME: " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host $folderName -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $contents = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $thisFolder -File -Force -Recurse

    $numFiles = ($contents | Measure-Object ).Count;
    $displayFiles = ('{0:N0}' -f $numFiles)

    $numBytes = ($contents | Measure-Object -Property Length -sum).sum
    $displayBytes = ('{0:N0}' -f $numBytes)

    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host "FOREACH:Total Files Found:      " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host $displayFiles -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewLine
    Write-Host " files." -ForegroundColor Green


    Write-Host "FOREACH: Total Bytes Found:     " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host $displayBytes -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewLine
    Write-Host " bytes." -ForegroundColor Green

    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host "FOREACH: Beginning operation " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host "PSCUSTOMOBJECT" -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host " on folder " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host $thisFolder -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host ", please wait..." -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host " "

#   $childFiles = $contents | Where-Object {!($_.PsIsContainer)}

    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host "FOREACH.THISFOLDER: " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewLine
    Write-Host $folderName -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "FOREACH.THISFOLDER.FILECOUNT: " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewLine
    Write-host $displayFiles  -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "FOREACH.THISFOLDER.SIZE.BYTES: " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewLine
    Write-Host $displayBytes  -ForegroundColor Yellow

#   PAUSE
    
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        'folderName' = $folderName
        $columnDate = $numFiles
    }
#Write-Host "============================================================" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
}
$folderSummary | Export-Csv $outputFile -Append -Force


There is nothing much to do except import the CSV, add the new date as a property name where necessary and then export it.
Have the relevant pieces of code, tested on 5.1 and 7.4
# Get the pre-formatted date.  
$columnDate = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy/MM/dd'

# Import the existing CSV as a List.  
# I suggest specifying the delimeter character both here and in Export-Csv.  
if (Test-Path $outputFile) { [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]$CsvContent = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $outputFile -Delimiter ',' }
# if the file doesn't exist or is empty, create a empty list.  
if ($null -eq $CsvContent) { $CsvContent = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new() }


foreach ($thisFolder in $rootFolders.FullName) {

    $folderName = Split-Path $thisFolder -Leaf

    $contents = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $thisFolder -File -Recurse -Force 

    $numFiles = ($contents | Measure-Object ).Count

    # check if there already is a line with the name of the current directory.  
    if ($CsvContent | Where-Object -Property folderName -EQ -Value $folderName) { 
        # get the index of the line.  
        $index = $CsvContent.FindIndex({ $folderName -eq $args[0].folderName })
        # if the line doesn't have a column with the current date as name, add it with the
        # number of files as value.  
        if (-not $CsvContent[$index].$columnDate) { 
            $CsvContent[$index] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $columnDate -Value $numFiles 
        }
        # uncomment the following line if you want to update the values of the current day when
        # running the script.  
        # else { if ($numFiles -ne $CsvContent[$index].$columnDate) { $CsvContent[$index].$columnDate = $numFiles } }
    }
    # if there is no line with the current folder as name, add folder and date values.  
    else { 
        $CsvContent.add(
            [PSCustomObject] @{
                'folderName' = $folderName
                $columnDate  = $numFiles
            }
        )
    }

    
}
# export the list to CSV
$CsvContent | Export-Csv $outputFile -Force -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' 

